# Format Date in Jtable/ResultSet

Tags: java, date, jtable

I am having trouble displaying `Date`s in the format I want in my `JTable`. My `JTable` has been created using a ResultSet and lists.

I tried the following in `getValueAt(.)` but no luck:

```
        if(value instanceof Date)
        {
            //System.out.println("isDate");
            DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
            value = f.format(value);
            Date parsed  = (Date) value;
            try {
                parsed = (Date) f.parse(value.toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            value = parsed.toString();
        }
```

The `println(.)` is never printed so it isn't even getting to that. The Format that is being displayed is `Apr 10, 1992` but I want `04/10/92`

While we are on the topic of `Date` in `JTables`... I have `isCellEditable(.)` as true but I cannot edit the Date cells. How do you do this?

Comment: Check if your 'instanceof' condition is refering to java.util.Date or to java.sql.Date.

Comment: Any exceptions and stacktraces? Post them.

Comment: Well the resultset gets sql.Date I believe. No exceptions or errors

Comment: Must admit I'm surprised the OP accepted the response over the reusable FormatRenderer I provided below. Given that the above code is basically a hack to reset the value used by the renderer, I would think it would be more straight forward to override the setValue() method of the renderer. Is that not the way the API was designed to be used? Its also the approach shown in the link to the Swing tutorial given above. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I like both the answers. Can't accept everyone :\ Sorry - wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not override `getValue`, use a [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) instead:

```
TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        if( value instanceof Date) {
            value = f.format(value);
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column);
    }
};

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tableCellRenderer);
```

Comment: have a read here
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Answer (score 6):

> The Format that is being displayed is
>   Apr 10, 1992

Sounds like a toString() representation of the Date is being stored in the TableModel and not a Date Object. So you need to check how your data is copied from the ResultSet to the TableModel. Make sure you are using the resultSet.getObject() method. Or maybe the problem is that you are storing a String in your database that is formatted the way you see it.

Anyway, once you are able to actually store a Date object in the TableModel, check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) which allows you to create a custom renderer with a customized date format in a single line of code.

Comment: +1, I don't think you are missing something. This approach is better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a subclass of DefaultTableCellRenderer and override `setValue(Object)` then set the cell renderer for the whole column.

```
public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public DateCellRenderer() { super(); }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

        setText((value == null) ? "" : sdf.format(value));
    }
}
```

Then in your user code do something like `JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setCellRenderer(new DateCellRenderer());`

Answer (score -5):

There is a third party add on available.. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Just add it via nuget, move the scripts to your content scripts file. Add this line (example)

Javascript:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/moment.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then we change our field declaration in jtable.

Javascript:

```
DateAdded: {
                        title: 'Date added',
                        width: '20%',
                        sorting: false,
                        display: function (data) {
                            return moment(data.record.DateAdded).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                        }
                    }
```