# add date format into a jtable without jchooser

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I got a database in as400 a IBM server, and display some data in a jtable and the date for example shows like that ddmmyy (290617) but I want in a date format like this dd/mm/yy (29/06/17) How can I do this? I am doing a Jframe in netbeans to show the table in the frame

Comment: Set a custom renderer for the column using the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2412120/243373) link.

Comment: Thanks!! that helps!!